# Trying to edit link styles within a div

Tags: css, html

so I'm having a bit of a tough time figuring this out.

I want to edit some links within a specific div, seems simple enough right?

Just put

`#mydiv a:link {color:#B40404}`

However it does not seem to be working for me! Below is my code:

```
<div id="leftcontent"><a href="http://google.de"><div id="MYDIV">why this is no work</div></a>
```

CSS:

```
#MYDIV {
background-image: url(http://mypicture.com/mypic.jpg);
width:290px;
height:280px;
font-family:Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif;
padding:25px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#MYDIV a:link {color:#B40404; }
```

I have no idea why this isn't working.  Any help appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

HTML should be like below (a tag inside the div)

```
<div id="leftcontent">
<div id="MYDIV"><a href="http://google.de">why this is no work</a></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#MYDIV a{color:#B40404; text-decoration:none}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rb7cc/)**

---

In your case (div inside the a tag) you need not to write id name in css directly write style for a tag

`a{color:#B40404; text-decoration:none` }

**or**

```
#leftcontent a{color:#B40404; text-decoration:none }
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/rb7cc/2/)**

Comment: Yep, you've got your `div` inside the `a` tag - it should be the other way around.

Comment: But the thing is I want the whole div to be hyperlinked - so the background image included, not just the text which is why I set it up this way.

Comment: So, it seems that is likely the problem - however is there anyway I can hyperlink the whole background image?  As what I did originally worked in hyperlinking the whole background and text - however it didn't let me edit the link decorations.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is selecting an  tag INSIDE a  tag.  You either need to do the following:

```
a #MYDIV { /* css code */ }
```

or

```
<div id="MYDIV"><a>My link here</a></div>
```

EDIT:

I just read your comment on the other page.  In that case, you need to add either a class or an ID to the  and then reference that.

```
<div id="leftcontent"><a href="http://google.de" id="myLink"><div id="MYDIV">why this is no work</div></a>
```

**CSS**

```
#myLink { /* add style here */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="leftcontent"><div id="MYDIV"><a href="http://google.de">why this is no work</a></div>
```

in css

```
#MYDIV a:link {color:#B40404; }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need not style the hyperlink in your case.

Since the styling would ultimately would be applied to **your div is enclosed within the anchor tag**. So give the **color: #your_hex_code** to the **#MYDIV** which would suffice your need. That is what you need.

If you made a mistake in the html, Sowmya answer is perfect.

**Optional:**

Moreover you can use jquery to style that, $("#your anchor").parent().css or use closest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this way is not a correct formating in coding html this will not validate in html validator

```
<div id="leftcontent">
  <a href="http://google.de">
  <div id="MYDIV">why this is no work</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

instead of that do this

```
<div id="leftcontent">
  <div id="MYDIV">
  <a href="http://google.de">sample</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

if you want the whole `div` link add basic style in your `div` `a`

css

```
#MYDIV {
float:left;
}

#MYDIV a {
float:left;
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
```